# Cannot get PyMeshLab running (filter_sketchfab.dll does not seem to be a Qt Plugin.)

Tags: python-3.x, pymeshlab

im absolutely new to this and struggle with following the tutorial from PyMeshLab (https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html).

What i want to do:

- open a file (e.g. xyz.ply - point cloud) via PyMeshLab
- some filter action
- save filtered file (e.g. as xyz.obj)

My "code" is stitched together from the tutorias "Load Mesh", "Apply a Filter" and "Save Mesh".

It prompts already a warning when importing the library

import pymeshlab
..

->

Warning:
Unable to load the following plugins:

```
filter_sketchfab.dll: filter_sketchfab.dll does not seem to be a Qt Plugin.
```

Cannot load library C:\Users\bvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymeshlab\lib\plugins\filter_sketchfab.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also get this warning. Still, it seems to work except for print functions like "MeshSet.print_filter_list()", which you might have copied from the example code. You can easily replace the print functions with functions on module level:

```
import pymeshlab
pymeshlab.print_pymeshlab_version()
filters = pymeshlab.filter_list()
print(filters)
pymeshlab.print_filter_parameter_list('discrete_curvatures')
```

Results:

```
PyMeshLab 0.2 based on MeshLab 2020.12d
['alpha_complex_shape', 'ambient_occlusion', 'annulus', 'box_cube', ... 'voronoi_sampling', 'voronoi_scaffolding', 'voronoi_vertex_coloring']
Please note: some parameters depend on the mesh(es) used as input of the 
filter. Default values listed here are computed on a 1x1x1 cube 
(pymeshlab/tests/sample/cube.obj), and they will be computed on the input mesh
if they are left as default.
surface_reconstruction_screened_poisson filter - list of parameter names:
    visiblelayer : bool = False
    depth : int = 8
    fulldepth : int = 5
    cgdepth : int = 0
    scale : float = 1.1
    samplespernode : float = 1.5
    pointweight : float = 4
    iters : int = 8
    confidence : bool = False
    preclean : bool = False
```

Other MeshSet functions work for me without issues, e.g.:

```
ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh('test.ply')
ms.apply_filter('discrete_curvatures')
ms.save_current_mesh(output_vis)
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint! Works actually.

Comment: @BjoH if this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted